# Background Image distortion in IE10 and moving the background with content flow?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a background image and a form which i have placed at the center of this webpage.

For background size to be working in ie 8 i have used `background-size.htc polyfill`

My requirement is background image should move with form content flow , that means when error messages appears below each input field the height of the form will increase that should also increase the height of the background image ,it should be relative to the bg image.Currently,its working in all browsers except ie what shoud i do for that?

Another thing in ie10 same bg image distorts? I'm attaching the screen shot of it.

[image]

Comment: where is your tried code ???

Comment: @Sajad I have used div and given background image and size to it.

Comment: @Kingisback, if you like to stretch that background image with screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the background image to entire browser window at all times. please try this,

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```