# IE10 Background Image Artifacts on Resize

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm looking for some help or documentation around what I think is an IE10 render/repaint bug.

There is a content-containing element on a page. It has a background image positioned to `center bottom`. In the case of the build I am working on, the background image is dynamically injected by the CMS — hence the reprehensible inline style. Content exists on page load but is hidden; to be revealed when the user expands an accordion-type UI element.

```
<div class="background-element" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/1500/100');">
    <div class="foreground-element">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Some Content</h1>
            <p>Some filler copy. Some filler copy. Some filler copy.</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/CJPGG/)

**Initial State**
[image: Expected, closed]

The expected behavior is that, as the revealed content expands the container, the background image moves with the container. This is how it works in most browsers.

**Expected Open State** (after animation)
[image: Expected, open]

In IE10, though, the image is fractured along the border of the contained element, and repeated at intervals (directly related to the speed of the transition) in the container itself.

**IE10 Open State** (after animation)
[image: IE10, open]

It looks like it may be related to [Kingisback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1948425/kingisback)'s question, [Background Image distortion in IE10 and moving the background with content flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22374444/5796134) but differs in that the background in this case is neither `fixed` nor set to `cover` so [Shaheer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3413797/shaheer)'s answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promote `background-element` to a new composite layer via CSS.

```
.background-element {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: That does it, yes! Any idea why it is happening to begin with?

Comment: IE10 must have some bug in how it re-renders/composites a background image when the background image is sharing a layer with another element. By promoting an element to its own layer, GPU hardware acceleration kicks in and the composite stage won't be disturbed by neighboring repaints.

Comment: Short answer: "Because IE".